# Can I add a value to a variable key in an array whose name is also a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to sort a list of classes (for a gym) which occur at certain times on certain days. I'm creating an array for each day of the week (if it doesn't already exist) using the value of the day from the current class. So, I'm looping through the classes, and using the following code in the `foreach` loop:

`if(empty($$day)) $$day = array();`

So now I have an array named $Monday, for example. Why can I use:

`array_push($$day,$post);`

but not

`$$day[] = $post;`?

I get a white screen with the code above. This is important because ideally I would grab the start time of the class, and use the following code, before performing a `ksort()`:

```
$$day[$time] = $post;
```

Is this just something I can't do in PHP?

Comment: White screen usually means syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: have You tried: ${$day}[] = $post

Comment: Plus, you should (probably) edit your question as to how you're using `ksort()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
${$day}[] = $post;
```

## Explanation

It's syntactically just not allowed to write `$$var[] = ...;` which will give you:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Those curly braces are sometimes required in PHP when you do some deep PHP magic. Also when referencing more complex structures within double quoted strings like this `"Here come some {$complex['value']}";`

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for more details.